# Too much recursion error when a classfield is not declared

Tags: javascript

If we declare a class like this:

```
class client{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name
  }

  get name()
  {
    return this.name ; 
  }
  set name(val)
  {
    this.name = val ;
  }
}
```

Instantiate
it will give an error ( too much recursion) and that normal because the setter will call itself.

```js
class client{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name
  }

  get name()
  {
    return this.name ; 
  }
  set name(val)
  {
    this.name = val ;
  }
}

let cl = new client();
```

But when i declare 'name' as class field i don't get that error, I don't understand why.

```js
class client{
  name = null ; 

  constructor(name){
    this.name = name
  }

  get name()
  {
    return this.name ; 
  }
  set name(val)
  {
    this.name = val ;
  }
}

let p = new client(); 
console.log(p) ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** You can't have both a data property and an accessor property with the same name on the same object, and if you have a data property on an object, any property with the same name on its prototype won't be used (unless you do so explicitly). The `name` class field definition creates an own data property on the object being constructed.

---

In the first case (as I think you know), `this.name` inside the `name` setter calls the `name` setter again, recursing until you run out of stack. (And the same for the getter, if you used it.)

So what's different when you have that `name` field definition there?

The way class fields are defined, that `name` definition creates an **own** property on the instance being created, as though you had this code at the beginning of the constructor (just after a `super` call if this were a subclass):

```
constructor(name) {
    // Definition of `name` field:
    Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
        value: undefined,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
    });
    // Remainder of constructor code:
    this.name = name;
}
```

Since it's an `own` property, `this.name` resolves to that data property, not to the accessor property on the prototype that the `get name` and `set name` accessor definitions create. So those accessors on `p`'s prototype are never used.

You can see that if you look at the definition of the property in your second example:

```js
class client {
  name = null; 

  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  get name()
  {
    return this.name ; 
  }
  set name(val)
  {
    this.name = val ;
  }
}

let p = new client(); 
console.log(p) ;
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(p, "name"));
```

If you want to have the accessor property, you could use a private field, which is quite new but supported in modern environments:

```js
class Client {
    #name = null; 
  
    constructor(name) {
        this.#name = name;
    }
  
    get name() {
        return this.#name; 
    }

    set name(val) {
        this.#name = val;
    }
}

let p = new Client("Joe"); 
console.log(p.name);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(p, "name")); // undefined
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(p), "name")); // accessor
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```